# Why are there no Hash/PartialEq/Eq implementations for std::cell::Ref

Tags: rust

Given the type [`std::cell::Ref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.Ref.html), it seems to be basically a pointer. Yet it doesn't have `Hash`, `PartialEq` or `Eq` trait implementations. Is there any fundamental reasons these traits haven't been added?

Comment: is not deref will allow to be use as the real type ?

Comment: I found [this related issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/24372) which concludes with *"We didn't believe there was a clear way to implement this right now as all current strategies had downsides"* but doesn't elaborate.

Comment: From that related issue: "These implementations, as added here, wouldn't enable something like `MutexGuard<i32> == i32`, but that's arguably something we'd like to work. Adding that, however, precludes `MutexGuard<i32> == MutexGuard<i32>`".

Comment: @Stargateur - it's no big deal if you have a `Ref<Foo>` (just shove `&` in front of both cases to `Deref`). The problem is when you have `Vec<Ref<Foo>>` or `Option<Ref<Foo>>`, or structures containing `Ref<Foo>` - then there is a lot of boilerplate.

Comment: I think option has a `as_deref()` method. I didn't used Cell API much so I fail to see clear use case anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Ref` type provides a `Deref` trait for doing comparing, so you could just dereference it to check for equality. Similar types like `MutexGuard`, `RwLockReadGuard` and `RwLockWeiteGuard` also implement `Deref` but not any of `Eq`, `Hash` etc.

There have been some discussions on implementing these traits on these types but none of the approach was feasible. So they just never got implemented.